# PYQT Update TableWidget Multiple Times Per Seconds Without Freezing/Crashing

Tags: python, pyqt

I am trying to make a program that has tasks which are shown in a tablewidget with the status, it then in a thread tries doing a certain task and then updates the  tablewidget with the status. The updates can happen multiple times per second. So my problem is, if I try updating from the main thread the GUI becomes unresponsive even if I use signals and slots. If I use threads to update, it works for a while but then crashes at random times. What should I do?

EDIT

I do not want to post the code on here, if possible can you email me sneakertown45@gmail.com, thanks!

Comment: You should edit your question and post the actual code that is causing the problem.

Comment: Also, you should ensure the code is a [MCVE] (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem.